# Can I declare a year somehow in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to delclare a year such as :

```
DECLARE @Year varchar
```

and populate this with something such as :

```
select @Year = year('2011')
```

Can I do this or must I create an entire DATE and populate it with filler information?

I wish to have a reuseable year vairable rthat I can inject into my queries.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

I performed this google [search](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=declare+@year+in+sql&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=f441d7c040dfef71) and also this google [search](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=declare++a+year+variable+in+sql&aq=f&aqi=&aql=f&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=f441d7c040dfef71)

I think I may be on to a solution but, if there is a quick way please let me know.  I will update if I figure it out.

I believe I need to add some additional information for clarification.

I need this variable in order to perform some date comparisons on dates that are in my database.  I want to check to verify that the variable @Year is equal to the year of the date in the database.

```
YEAR(EntryDate) = YEAR('2011')
```

or

my new method

```
YEAR(EntryDate) = YEAR(cast(@year as varchar))
```

This is a part of my where statement in my query.

Comment: Why as a string not an int and why `varchar` not `char(4)` if you are using a string? Also `DECLARE @Year varchar` without a size will truncate at 1 character.

Comment: If I use the int I must cast to a varchar in order to use it with YEAR(), or am I wrong?

Comment: `SELECT YEAR(@somedate)` returns an `int` not a string.

Comment: see my edit to my answer for why **NOT** to use your year as a `varchar`

Comment: You seem to be treating `YEAR` as though it has some special significance and if it is on the LHS side of a comparison it must be on the right. This is **not** the case!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 - Why make it a `varchar` instead of an `int`?  You want `2011` not `Two thousand and eleven` right?

2 - You can always use the `YEAR(GETDATE())` function to get the current year.

Syntax for a numerical value would be

```
DECLARE @Year int = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

**EDIT:**

Example of why it is bad to use `varchar` for a number comparison:

With `int`:

**21 < 2010 = TRUE**

With `varchar`:

**21 < 2010 = FALSE**

Comment: Ok, taking what you just posted I was able to create something akin to that which I was looking for. I have DECLARE @year int select DATENAME('2011', GETDATE()) and then I can use it with YEAR(cast(@year as varchar))

Comment: @Michael - why `varchar` though?   You realize comparisons don't work like you expect with `varchar`s right?

Comment: @JNK I was simply using the varchar to allow the use of YEAR('2011') originally, I am definitely open to better avenues for a variable version rather than the 15 or so YEAR('2011') I have in my query. ;)

Comment: @Michael - you can always cast an `int` to a `varchar`, i.e. `CAST(@Year as varchar)` if you need it in a string.  If it's a numerical value you should keep it as a number data type though, otherwise you may get some unexpected results.

Comment: @JNK I see your point and concede that the int is a much better choice.  Thank you for your assistance and suggestions!

Comment: @Michael. Just declare a variable like `DECLARE @TargetYear int = 2011` and use that. I don't understand why you are using `YEAR('2011')`